# how to slice strings inside array into another array using python

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, slice

I want to slice certain parts of a string inside a list into another list,
for example consider their is the list data:

```
data = ["xbox 360 | 13000 | new","playstation 4 | 30000 | new","playstation 3 | 30000 | old","playstation 2 | 30000 | old"]
```

I want to slice each component into three,

```
product = ["xbox 360","playstation 4","playstation 3","playstation 2"]
cost = ["13000","30000","30000","30000"]
condition = ["new","new","old","old"]
```

please help me

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Did you try a for loop?

Comment: **@surya**, you can also use **list comprehension** with **reduce()** method to accomplish your task just with the use of 1 line statement  `products, cost, condition = reduce(lambda s1, s2: [s1[index] + [item.strip()] for index, item in enumerate(s2.split('|'))], data,[[], [], []])`.

Answer (score 4):

The following uses the common `zip(*...)` transpositioning pattern while splitting the strings on an appropriate separator:

```
>>> prd, cst, cnd = zip(*(s.split(' | ') for s in data))
>>> prd
('xbox 360', 'playstation 4', 'playstation 3', 'playstation 2')
>>> cst
('13000', '30000', '30000', '30000')
>>> cnd
('new', 'new', 'old', 'old')
```

Comment: `map(list,zip(*(s.split(' | ') for s in data)))`?

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through your list of data and then split each element. Then you can add that data to the `product`, `cost` and `condition` lists by using `.append()`:

```
data = ["xbox 360 | 13000 | new","playstation 4 | 30000 | new","playstation 3 | 30000 | old","playstation 2 | 30000 | old"]
product = []
cost = []
condition = []
for string in data:
    strSplit = string.split(" | ")
    product.append(strSplit[0])
    cost.append(strSplit[1])
    condition.append(strSplit[2])

print(product)
print(cost)
print(condition)
```

Result of the following code:

```
['xbox 360', 'playstation 4', 'playstation 3', 'playstation 2']
['13000', '30000', '30000', '30000']
['new', 'new', 'old', 'old']
```

Comment: Ah yes, I just used arrays as the question had the it as a tag. However you are definitely correct correct, I’ll update my answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

**@surya**, you can try any one of the below 2 approaches. The 1st one is very short which will give your all 3 lists just with an execution of one line statement. I have used he concept of **list comprehension** and **reduce()** function.

> Use **split()** to get the words separated with `|` for each of the list items.
>
> Use **strip()** to remove leading/trailing whitespaces.

### 1st way (one line statement)

> Just use `product, cost, condition = reduce(lambda s1, s2: [s1[index] + [item.strip()] for index, item in enumerate(s2.split('|'))], data,[[], [], []]);` and it will give your lists.

```
>>> data = ["xbox 360 | 13000 | new","playstation 4 | 30000 | new","playstation 3 | 30000 | old","playstation 2 | 30000 | old"]
>>>
>>> product, cost, condition = reduce(lambda s1, s2: [s1[index] + [item.strip()] for index, item in enumerate(s2.split('|'))], data,[[], [], []]);
>>>
>>> product
['xbox 360', 'playstation 4', 'playstation 3', 'playstation 2']
>>>
>>> cost
['13000', '30000', '30000', '30000']
>>>
>>> condition
['new', 'new', 'old', 'old']
>>>
```

### 2nd way

```
>>> data = ["xbox 360 | 13000 | new","playstation 4 | 30000 | new","playstation 3 | 30000 | old","playstation 2 | 30000 | old"]
>>>
>>> product = []
>>> cost = []
>>> condition = []
>>>
>>> for s in data:
...     l = [item.strip() for item in s.split("|")]
...     product.append(l[0])
...     cost.append(l[1])
...     condition.append(l[2])
...
>>> product
['xbox 360', 'playstation 4', 'playstation 3', 'playstation 2']
>>>
>>> cost
['13000', '30000', '30000', '30000']
>>>
>>> condition
['new', 'new', 'old', 'old']
>>>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ["xbox 360 | 13000 | new","playstation 4 | 30000 | new","playstation 3 | 30000 | old","playstation 2 | 30000 | old"]
product = [y.split("|")[0].strip() for y in data]
cost = [y.split("|")[1].strip() for y in data]
condition = [y.split("|")[2].strip() for y in data]
print(product)
print(cost)
print(condition)
```

**Output**

```
['xbox 360', 'playstation 4', 'playstation 3', 'playstation 2']
['13000', '30000', '30000', '30000']
['new', 'new', 'old', 'old']
```